How to invoke methods with arguments for any return and argument type?
I'm developing a scripting engine for an embedded system automation project. One requirement to accomplish this is to store instructions sequentially to be run later. The project also has to be in C#.
The "instructions" are any method that the user wishes to run, with the required parameter. They don't have a specific pattern. Most of the methods are async and run with an await, since they are related to the response of the hardware. After creating the list of methods/arguments, running instructions.Execute() would run the methods sequentially.
Probably because I'm new to C#, I can't seem to find a way to accomplish this achieving the necessary flexibility.
Summarizing, I'll have an Instruction class where each instance will store a method and it's parameters.
The method can be any method (returns void, Task, object, any type) and can have any parameter (void, single parameter, multiple parameter, preferably being able to externalize variables with things like pointers).
I've made a proof of concept for the entire system and this part was solved with generic types. The issue is that this solution will only work for single parameter methods.
 public class Instruction<T, U>
{
    /// The method to be executed. The method must have one argument. 
    private readonly Func<T, U>? _Function;
    /// The method to be executed. The method must have one argument. 
    private readonly Action<T>? _Action;
    /// The argument going to be passed to the method
    private readonly T _Argument; // TODO: This could be a list of arguments for more than 1 argument methods
    
    public Instruction(Func<T, U> function, T argument) 
    {
        _Function = function;
        _Argument = argument;
        _Action = null;
    }

    public Instruction(Action<T> function, T argument) 
    {
        _Function = null;
        _Argument = argument;
        _Action = function;
    }

    /// Executes the function(argument) passed in the constructor.
    public async Task<bool> Execute()
    {
        if (_Action != null)
        {
            _Action(_Argument);
            return true;
        }
        else if (_Function == null) // _Action and _Function is null.
        {
            return true;
        }

        // Invoke the function with the argument
        var result = _Function(_Argument);

        // Check if the result is a Task
        if (result is Task task)
        {
            // If it's a Task, await it
            await task;
        }
        else if (result is Task<U> taskWithResult)
        {
            // If it's a Task<U>, await it and ignore the result
            await taskWithResult;
        }
        else
        {
            // If it's neither, it's a synchronous operation, so no awaiting is necessary
            // This branch is executed for synchronous methods like Console.WriteLine
        }
        return true;
    }
} 

I've also tried to solve it with delegates, but no luck.
Bellow is a silly example on how my implementation is used:
Test test = new Test();

test.AddInstruction(Console.WriteLine, "Silly Example");
for (var index = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    test.AddInstruction(HMI.ButtonPress, index); 
    test.AddInstruction(Task.Delay, 250);
}

test.AddInstruction(ECU.TurnOnBlinker, LIGHTS.LeftBlinker); 
test.AddInstruction(Task.Delay, 1000);
test.AddInstruction(ECU.TurnOffBlinker, LIGHTS.LeftBlinker); 
test.AddInstruction(Console.WriteLine, "Executed all instructions");

test.Execute();

But now I need more flexibility. I'm at a loss for some work days now, can anyone give me a north?

Why do you build one? Stand on the shoulders of giants. There are several scripting engines available for c#/.net including but not restricted to c#-script, Lua, python,...

If you want to store and execute methods with varying signatures and parameters, you can use a combination of delegates, Func<>, and Action<> with dynamic invocation, you need Instruction class to store a delegate and its parameters can handle synchronous and asynchronous methods and create a list to hold the instructions and a method to execute them.This is sample code maight help you achive that:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public abstract class Instruction
{
    public abstract Task ExecuteAsync();
}

public class SyncInstruction : Instruction
{
    private readonly Action _action;

    public SyncInstruction(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public override Task ExecuteAsync()
    {
        _action();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class AsyncInstruction : Instruction
{
    private readonly Func<Task> _func;

    public AsyncInstruction(Func<Task> func)
    {
        _func = func;
    }

    public override async Task ExecuteAsync()
    {
        await _func();
    }
}

public class InstructionWithParams : Instruction
{
    private readonly Delegate _delegate;
    private readonly object[] _parameters;

    public InstructionWithParams(Delegate del, params object[] parameters)
    {
        _delegate = del;
        _parameters = parameters;
    }

    public override async Task ExecuteAsync()
    {
        var result = _delegate.DynamicInvoke(_parameters);
        if (result is Task task)
        {
            await task;
        }
    }
}


public class InstructionExecutor
{
    private readonly List<Instruction> _instructions = new List<Instruction>();

    public void AddInstruction(Instruction instruction)
    {
        _instructions.Add(instruction);
    }

    public async Task ExecuteAsync()
    {
        foreach (var instruction in _instructions)
        {
            await instruction.ExecuteAsync();
        }
    }
}


public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var executor = new InstructionExecutor();

        // Add a synchronous method
        executor.AddInstruction(new SyncInstruction(() => Console.WriteLine("Sync method executed")));

        // Add an asynchronous method
        executor.AddInstruction(new AsyncInstruction(async () => 
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Async method executed");
        }));

        // Add a method with parameters
        executor.AddInstruction(new InstructionWithParams((Action<int, string>)((x, y) => 
            Console.WriteLine($"Method with params: {x}, {y}")), 42, "Hello"));

        // Add an asynchronous method with parameters
        executor.AddInstruction(new InstructionWithParams((Func<int, string, Task>)(async (x, y) =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine($"Async method with params: {x}, {y}");
        }), 42, "World"));

        // Execute all instructions sequentially
        await executor.ExecuteAsync();
    }
}

This is more simple example :
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    // Define an Instruction class to store method delegates and parameters
    public class Instruction
    {
        public Delegate Method { get; set; }
        public object[] Parameters { get; set; }
    }

    // Example methods
    public static void PrintMessage(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Message: {message}");
    }

    public static async Task<int> ComputeAsync(int x, int y)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000); // Simulate async work
        return x + y;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var instructions = new List<Instruction>();

        // Add instructions (method delegates and parameters)
        instructions.Add(new Instruction
        {
            Method = new Action<string>(PrintMessage),
            Parameters = new object[] { "Hello, world!" }
        });

        instructions.Add(new Instruction
        {
            Method = new Func<int, int, Task<int>>(ComputeAsync),
            Parameters = new object[] { 10, 20 }
        });

        // Execute instructions sequentially
        foreach (var instruction in instructions)
        {
            instruction.Method.DynamicInvoke(instruction.Parameters);
        }
    }
}


If I understand right you want to use functions with unknown count of parameters and types.
First you should replace Func and Action with Delegate. You can .DynamicInvoke(object[] parameters) -> object it.
using System;

public class Instruction {
    private readonly Delegate _Function;
    
    private readonly object[] _Arguments;

    public Instruction(Delegate function, params object[] args) {
        _Function = function;
        _Arguments = args;
    }

    public async Task<bool> Execute() {
        var result = _Function.DynamicInvoke(_Arguments);
        
        // Your Task logic
    }
}

This way you'll be able to create instructions like:
var instruction = new Instruction(SomeMethod, 1, new Person("Nick"), false, null);
instruction.Execute();

It looks like an easier version of Reflection. I think you should check what Reflection is in C#. It's a strong tool for getting information about assemblies, modules, types and its constructors, methods. It can be really useful in your case in future.

The simplest implementation, is delegate (action/func/Task).
Existing popular demonstrations, similar to Commands.
If you need a complex implementation, there may be 3 goals:

Windows Workflow.
Task scheduler.
csx(OmniSharp/dotnet-script).


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
